# prolog - check if given list matches a pattern and replace certain elements

Tags: list, prolog

I am encountering problems with the following prolog code:

```
valid(X, Y) :-
    append([E1 | T2], [E1 | T3], X1), append([E1|T1], X1, X),
    append([E2 | T2], [E2 | T3], Y1), append([E2|T1], Y1, Y),
    E2 is E1 + 1.
```

What I am trying to do is: for a given list X, check if it matches the pattern `[E1, ..., E1, ..., E1, ...]`; if it does, replace all `E1` with `E1+1`. 
There could be any number of elements in the `...` parts, i.e. `T1`, `T2` and `T3` could be of any length.

For example, my intended output is:

```
?- valid([1,5,1,6,7,1,8], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,1,7,1], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 2] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,7,8], Y).
false.
```

But now the actual output I got is:

```
?- valid([1,5,1,6,7,1,8], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack

?- valid([1,5,6,7,8], Y).
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

The problem is, prolog will attempt to try out infinitely many lengths of `T1`, `T2` and `T3`, and therefore never stops. So when my input list `X` does not match the pattern, it keeps running until out of memory space.

Is there any way to fix my code so that it stops when all possible answers are found (could be more than one) or when X does not match the pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Append/3` predicate is not steadfast, so it evaluates it's parameters in the beginning. So you need to move the rule that evaluates X in the front like:

```
valid(X, Y) :-
    append([E1|T1], X1, X),append([E1 | T2], [E1 | T3], X1),
    append([E2|T1], Y1, Y),append([E2 | T2], [E2 | T3], Y1),
    E2 is E1 + 1.
```

Since X is evaluated first append will not lead to try out infinitely many lengths and similarly the second append.

Some examples:

```
?- valid([1,5,1,6,7,1,8], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,1,7,1], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 2] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,7,8], Y).
false.
```

I would prefer solving the problem with some simple recursion and counting appearances of E1 (and replacing with E2 in output list) since append can a bit tricky...

So for example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

valid([H|T], [H2|T2]):-  H2 #= H+1 ,valid(H,T,T2,1).

valid(_,[],[],3).
valid(H,[H|T1],[H2|T2],Count):- H2 #= H+1, Count1 #= Count+1,valid(H,T1,T2,Count1).  
valid(H,[H1|T1],[H1|T2],Count):- dif(H1,H), valid(H,T1,T2,Count).
```

And some examples:

```
?- valid([1,5,1,6,7,1,8], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,1,7,1], Y).
Y = [2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 2] ;
false.

?- valid([1,5,6,7,8], Y).
false.

?- valid(X, [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8]).
X = [1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 1, 8] ;
false.
```

Using CLPFD library makes the predicate more relational, so as you can see in the last example above you can make queries like: `valid(X, [2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8]).` while before you couldn't (with previous solution).

Here is another alternative way:

```
new(H,H,R):- R is H+1.
new(H,N,N):- dif(N,H). 

valid([H|T], Y):- findall(X1, (member(X1,[H|T]),X1 = H) , L), 
                  length(L,3), maplist(new(H),[H|T],Y).
```

Comment: Glad to help !!!, I already tried to solve with recursion and edited my answer, hope it helps !!.